# Django Check if Integer Exists in Database Field Array

Tags: arrays, json, django, orm, model

I have a database with a field that is a "pseudo" `array`. This `array` holds integer values. My implementation is as follows:

```
attendees = models.TextField(null=True) # declaring the integer array
```

When I say pseudo, I mean that I am using `json` to make it into an array.

```
attendees=json.dumps(members)
```

Now the `attendees` column will contain something like this `["1", "2", "3"]`

So I want to check if attendees will contain the value "`1`" for example. Essentially, I want something like this:

```
eventList = Events.objects.all().filter(user_id in Event.attendees) # I know this isn't the correct syntax
```

Any ideas on how to do this as efficiently as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [`__contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#contains)

```
 .filter(attendees__contains='"{}"'.format(user_id))
```

<sub>Although the question remains why this isn't a separate model or JSONField/ArrayField...</sub>